# Why does my image rotate differently when I change screen space to camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using this script and when I change my canvas to screenspace-camera, the code functions differently.

```
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        RectTransform rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        Vector2 mousePosition = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position);

        Vector2 offset = mousePosition - initialPosition;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - angleOffset;

        Debug.Log(angle);

        rectTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);

        angularVelocity = (angle - previousAngle) / Time.deltaTime;

        previousAngle = angle;
    }
```

I've tried adjusting the mousePosition based on camera, but without success.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what mode you changed to what other?